# Trying to build a date lookup that populates the result for each day

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a returns spreadsheet for investing - I am using today() and then displaying the rate of return - the trick is i'm trying to get that to then almost "vlookup" against 365 days below and add that return to the corresponding date of the year.

Can only get today()

if statements dont let me populate the next cell over , vlookups dont seem to work either - of course I can just do it manually - but would love to automate this process.

a1 = today() a2 = 4.99% (this changes daily using googlefinance and the rate of the investments)

the goal if today is 6/1/19 that that would populate the 4.99% in the cell next to 6/1/19 then when the day hits 7/1/19 the rate of return that day would populate against the 7/1

obviously will have 365 dates in my sheet.

Many many thanks :)

Comment: The issue is that formula cannot change the value of another cell, you will need to look at Macros / VBA to achieve this task... Feel free to have a go and come back with your code if you need any help (it doesn't need to be working code, we'll be happy to help you along providing you have had a go at it)

Answer (score 0):

Well once you get your data set up then your formula for today could possibly be something like this which hopefully will give you some ideas to use for however you EXACTLY set everything up:

=VLOOKUP(Today(), MyNameForRangeOfData, 2)

Where 2 is the 2nd column in your range...